# Adding value in raster file from attribute table in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster

I have a raster (in tif format) with one band (an ID number). I also have an attribute table with several fields(columns) for each ID number of the raster file. For instance,
raster.tif: 1 band (ID)
table.txt : ID, field

So, the two files have a common value (the ID field).

How can I add the column "field" from the table.txt in the raster.tif ?